# Find necessary and sufficient conditions that an element is not irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Give $p$ is a prime. Prove that $p$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ if and only if there are exist $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ that $p= m^2 + n^2$.**

I attempt to do reduction to absurdity but it's not really usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supose $p$ is reducible. Then $p$ has a non-trivial factorization, say $p=(a+bi)(c+di) \text { for }a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Z.$ Taking norms, we have $$p^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2).$$Since $p$ is prime, there are 3 possibilities (i) $$a^2+b^2=1,$$(ii)$$c^2+d^2=1,$$ or (iii) $$p=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2.$$ Suppose $a^2+b^2=1. $Then $a=\pm 1,b=0 \text { or } b= \pm 1,a=0.$ If $a= \pm 1,$then $ad=0,d=0,p= \pm c$ which is a trivial factorization of $p$. There is a similar contradiction if $b= \pm 1.$ So (i) is impossible. The proof that (ii) is impossible is the same. So we must have case (iii). Conversely, if $$p=m^2+n^2 \text { for }m,n \in \mathbb Z, \text { then } p=(m+ni)(m-ni)$$ Q.E.D.

Comment: Sorry, i think in the converse you go wrong. The problem give there exist $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ but not sure in $\mathbb{Z}$. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Tung Nguyen: The result I proved was correct but the result given in the question is incorrect. For example, 7 is iirreducible in Z[i] but 7 is the sum of the squares of 4 and 3i.